# Can't get clip-path to work with external svg

Tags: html, css, svg, clipping, clip-path

I'm trying to get an image clipped by a external svg file.

I can get it to work applying eg. a polygon directly to the css, but when I try to link it to an external svg, it's not working.

This is my image that needs to be clipped:

```html
<img src="{{ asset('/images/hero.jpg') }}" class="hero-image">
```

This is my svg

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Laag_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1366 706" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1366 706;" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="bg-clipping">
        <path d="M-0.6-15.6l76.8,612.4c0,0,6.6,104.8,108.4,107.2C243.8,705.3,1363,571.9,1363,571.9L1364.3,3L-0.6-15.6z"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>

</svg>
```

and here is my css

```css
.hero-image {
            @apply absolute w-full h-full;
            clip-path: url("#bg-clipping");
        }
```

Please save me, heroes of Stackoverflow. I've been struggling for a loooooong time now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the SVG is on a different URL, you're probably out of luck. Firefox is currently the only browser that supports this ([CanIUse chart footnote 2](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)).

If you're OK with it only working in Firefox, you can define the `clip-path` like so.

```css
.hero-image {
  clip-path: url("path/to/svg.svg#bg-clipping");
}
```

Interesting caveat: while it does work with relative URL's ([as demonstrated here](https://lab.iamvdo.me/css-svg-masks/#testC7)), it doesn't work with absolute URL's to a different domain ([demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/j84tgc0v/)). I can't find an explanation for this in the spec, it appears to be a bug.

---

When the SVG is on the same page as the image, it should work fine. Browser support is better.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.hero-image {
  min-height: 706px;
  clip-path: url("#bg-clipping");
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1366/706" class="hero-image">


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1366 706">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="bg-clipping">
        <path d="M-0.6-15.6l76.8,612.4c0,0,6.6,104.8,108.4,107.2C243.8,705.3,1363,571.9,1363,571.9L1364.3,3L-0.6-15.6z"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: i think in 2023 all major browser support it now